# GlobalHotKey not firing any events

Tags: c#

I googled around to find a way to have a GlobalHotKey on my C# Winform.

I saw [this](https://bloggablea.wordpress.com/2007/05/01/global-hotkeys-with-net/) tutorial and followed it.

**The issue I'm having now is that nothing is occurring once I press the designated key.(In this case, the ` key)**

[Here is the class I'm using](http://pastebin.com/0YJnAhdJ)

Here is the relevant code on my Form1.cs

```
Hotkey hk = new Hotkey();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hk.KeyCode = Keys.Oemtilde;
    hk.Windows = true;
    hk.Pressed += hk_Pressed;
    hk.Register(this);
}

private void hk_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("pressed");
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (hk.Registered)
    { hk.Unregister(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you set `hk.Windows = true;` which required you to press Windows+ ``, remove that line and press `, it will work